# Getting this update when trying to update proile pic firebaseAuth on Android

Tags: android, firebase

I keep getting the same error and the app stops working when I try and select an image to upload for user using google firease firebaseAuth on android. Here is the error I keep getting: Caused by:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq"
```

gradle build is as follows :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dissertation.studentscanner"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:16.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.3'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
```

Don't also forget to add in your top level `build.gradle` file, the following Google Service plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

Comment: Works perfect now when adding the pics to the storage but unfortunately when I resign in to the associated profiles, the images do not load. Could you help with this?

Comment: Good to hear that it worked! This is basically another problem that cannot be solved in a comment and using the data in this post. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question witn a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.